# Uniswap V3 Active Liquidity Provision

Tags: uniswap, ethereumjs, defi

I am trying out different strategies for UniSwap active liquidity management. I have been reading different articles on the best strategy and the most popular one seems to be using Bollinger Band.

I have a question regarding Bollinger Band. Based on my initial run for Bollinger Band, I ran into a scenario where there are way too many rebalancing resulting in heavy impermanent loss. Is this normal for Bollinger Band?

Also, are there any strategies I should follow? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bollinger bands are good, but I prefer 2.3 standard deviations to the default.
Also when automating my strategies, I overlap my positions on either side so that when my main position reaches a token ratio of 85/15 (or 15/85), the next position in line is in range.

At that point, I move 75% of the current position into the next, so I'm accruing fees on both, when the price is clearly moving into your next price range, move the rest of the liquidity over. If it's sitting on the brink, always leave some in each.

It takes some tweaking based on your token pairs, but tomorrow I will update this answer with my personal parameters for my ETH/USDC, and ETH/WBTC automated strategies.

Comment: Thank you very much @jon.bray.eth!

Comment: @user122663 Are you automating this using a contract to mint and deploy UNI-V3 NFTs, or are you utilizing an off-chain script to write to the UniSwap deployer contract and create new NFTs on the fly? This will better help me answer your question.

Comment: @user122663 Also, what pairs are you trading? I have tons of different small positions from a grid-bot I set up using Uni-V3. I've recently switched to a proprietary grid-bot strategy and no longer need the NFTs. If they're pairs you're using, I'd be happy to sell for less than mint cost.

Comment: Hi @jon.bray.eth, I am backtesting for the different strategies before deploying my own bot. I am primarily trading USDC/ETH

Comment: @user122663 I will attach some example repos I've written this evening for you to look at. Are you trying to maximize USD profit or accumulate ETH?
Also, if this is a long term strategy, have you considered ETH/WBTC? Less volatility = less impermanent loss (ex. 20x positions in the 0.045-0.085 BTC range is historically where ETH sits so there is little guessing as to what your max price should be as with ETH/USDC pair). You're also accumulating two assets that will both massively appreciate in price long term.

Comment: Hi @jon.bray.eth, sorry for the late reply. I am trying to maximise USD profit. I haven't exactly explored the ETH/WBTC pair. But I will take a look. Thanks

Comment: @user122663 No problem! I've actually set up some rebalancing and compounding protocols on Arbitrum, Polygon, and Ethereum that I think would work really well for you. ETH rebalance is signature based (no gas!) With the right range and rebalance schedule, 15-25% APR/day is not out of the question especially with prices appreciating short term.

Give me a shout on XMTP or Blockchat (etherscan) and I can walk you through maximizing profits.